# How could I display a checked checkbox based on it's value in the database?

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm new in C#, could you help me to solve my problem? I'm trying to display the checkbox checked based on its value in the database.

I have two checkbox

1. fullpayment
2. EMI

when i retrieve data from database it's should automatically checked the checkbox.

if it is fullpayment then fullpayment checkbox should check, if EMI then emi checkbox should check.

Answer (score 0):

Depends
If one of them must be checked
The you add a boolean column, Bit type in say Sql Server call it say FullPayment
So then you set the FullPayment Checkbox to that, and the EMI checkbox to !FullPayment

If say on a new record neither are checked User must pick one), then you could still use a FullPayment boolean and use it being null in the db to not set either.

If both can be the it's two booleans or my preferred solution for anything but scenario 1
Use an integer say PaymentState

```
0 = neither set
1 = Full Payment
2 = EMI
3 = Both
```

Then `FullPaymentCheckbox.Checked = (PaymentState & 1) > 0;`
and `EMICheckbox.Checked = (PaymentState & 2) > 0;`